# List not updating in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I tried to update a list . I tried the code in debug mode , and the code was executed without any errors. But the value was not updated. Why would this be? I have shared the code below.

```
foreach (var r in respondents)
            {
                foreach(var v in completesMap.VendorView)
                {
                    if(v.Value.Contains(r.Status))
                    {
                        r.Status=v.Key;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

completesMap.VendorView is a key-value pair which I hard-coded in appsettings.json file , respondents is a Dto

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line `r.Status=v.Key;` will it be hit?

Comment: Yes.. That line of code is getting executed. but the value is not changed.

Comment: May be `v.Key` is same as `r.Status`?

Comment: No.. I checked with different values

Comment: if someone proves to you that the code works, but you can't see it working, the problem is .... the rest of the code, the one that you are not showing, because that part of the code, the one that you are showing is working. Where can you see that the value is not updated?

Comment: After the first foreach..I'm returning respondents to be downloaded as an excel file.. i can see their that it is not updated @Iria

Comment: More on debugging: After the line is executed, do you see that `r.Status` has now a modified value? Moreover: when inspecting `respondents`, do you see the item with the modified status?

Comment: @KlausGütter .. no its not changing

Comment: Show us the definition of the class containing the Status property.

Comment: ok, so question, how do you know that it is that piece of code not working? I mean, it could be the case, that you are updating locally the values, and then look at your excel file, it is not updated, because you passed the old values, does it make sense? what I am after is to know if you have done a proper debugging

Comment: your code snippet is not enough to pin point the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example using your code and it works.
You can see how it works [at this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x5hwN1). You can also copy and paste that code to your IDE and debug it & see if it works at your machine also.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.. but this is not working for me..

Comment: You mean, if you copy and paste the same code from my link to your machine it doesn't work?

Comment: This code works well. @Roby A, you shold check the code and compare with your code what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
        List<Respondent> respondents = new List<Respondent>()
        {
            new Respondent { Status = "Active"},
            new Respondent { Status = "Active"},
            new Respondent { Status = "InActive"},
        };

        var completesMap = new Map
        {
            VendorView = new List<VendorView>()
            {
                new VendorView{ Value = "This is Active" , Key = "Key1" },
                new VendorView{ Value = "this is not active", Key = "Key2" }
            }
        };
        
        foreach (var r in respondents)
        {
            foreach (var v in completesMap.VendorView)
            {
                if (v.Value.Contains(r.Status))
                {
                    r.Status = v.Key;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        var x = respondents[1].Status;
```

Debugger Output

[image: Output]

Comment: still you are facing the issue , please share your complete method code and model details.